# Writing a function that parses a nested json file in python

Tags: python

**I have a json file that looks something like this:**

```
{
"mAutomaticTestCompleted": true,
"mAutomaticTestList": [
  {
    "mName": "acceleratorEntity",
    "mTestStatus": true,
    "mX": 3.8043518,
    "mY": 8.114105,
    "mZ": -3.3895721
  },
  {
    "mName": "barometerEntity",
    "mTestStatus": false,
    "mValue": 0
  }]
}
```

There are actually lots of fields like `mAutomaticTestlist`, all of them are lists of objects that look just like that.
I need to write a function that takes `device_name` and JSON itself as its arguments and returns the value of the `mTestStatus` field.

**Here's my attempt:**

```
def hasPassed(device_name, data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            if not isinstance(value, dict) and not isinstance(value, list):
                if key == 'mName' and value == device_name:
                    return data['mTestStatus']
                else:
                    return hasPassed(device_name, value)
            elif isinstance(data, list):
                for element in data:
                    return hasPassed(device_name, element)
```

The problem with this function is that it doesn't go over the whole JSON object.

---

**EDIT:**

So I would like my function to work this way:

```
hasPassed('barometerEntity', json_obj)
```

would return `False` cos that's the value of the 'mTestStatus' corresponding the device_name (which is barometerEntity in this case).

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you expect your output to look like?

Comment: How do the last three lines in your sample code work?

Comment: Are you looking to re-invent the wheel, or are you unaware that there is a json parser part of the python standard library? https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html   And how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835672/3402205

Comment: @vealkind I've just done it.

Comment: @GeoffLentsch No, in my case there may be lots of devices in the json file, all I know about it is its name and the function should return whether its mTestStatus is `True` or `False`. It should be done automatically like in the example provided above.

Comment: To clarify, your parameter `data` is already a python object (dict)? In other words, you've already parsed the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong code formatting, should be:

```
def hasPassed(device_name, data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        if 'mName' in data and data['mName'] == device_name :
            return data['mTestStatus']
        else :
            for k in data :
                if hasPassed(device_name, data[k]) : return True
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for element in data:
            if hasPassed(device_name, element) : return True
    return False
```

Last 3 lines -- move to the left.

And there should be return in the end of the function, that returns when your data is not `list` and not `dict` -- otherwise your sunction will return `None` and may crash something.

```
>>> hasPassed( 'barometerEntity', a)
False
>>> hasPassed( 'acceleratorEntity', a)
True
>>>
```

Comment: @Albert your `for key, value in data.items():` loop never goes beyond the first element, it just returns `hasPassed( 'something', true)`, because the first element is mAutomaticTestCompleted : true

Comment: Yeah, but have you tried running your code? I tryed copy-pasting it and it didn't work for me either. It just returns `None`...

Comment: @Albert please, try the latest version, works for me =)

Comment: Yeah it works now...I'm sorta in a mad rush so I made the stupid mistake...Thank you a lot, it does work as expected now!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import json

def hasPassed(device_name, data):

  test_list = json.loads(obj)["mAutomaticTestList"]

  for elt in test_list:
      if elt["mName"] == device_name: return elt["mTestStatus"]
```

Comment: No, in my case there may be lots of devices in the json file, all I know about it is its name and the function should return whether its mTestStatus is True or False. It should be done automatically like in the example provided in the question.
I definitely need recursion here, This is not the whole json file, I didn't post it here cos it's too big but there may be lots of fields like `mAutomaticTestList`

Comment: sorry but you should've provided a clearer json structure !